# Highlight Div using Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I want to highlight a div which is part of a form using fancybox.

```
<form>
  ...
  ...
  <div id='sub-form'>
    ...
    ...
  </div>
  ...
  ...
<form>
```

I want to show the div with `id = sub-form` in a popup window and also in the main page. When value of an element in the popup is changed then value of that element in the parent window should change accordingly.

Mean while i want to highlight that div.

I tried it using fancybox but fancybox is removing it from the form and also hiding from the parent window.

Is it possible to do with fancybox? OR any plugin is available to do this task? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't just add border of change background color of your div to be highlighted

Comment: NOPE.. It must be in a popup.

Comment: I hope you understand that it is not valid to have two elements having the same ID